# How to configure Google Analytics to track URL parameters as individual pages

Tags: javascript, parameters, google-analytics

I am creating a web application where I have pages with query parameters that change the content of that page based on the URL parameters.

For example, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wvsboPUjrGc will load a certain video based on the query parameter. How can I configure Google Analytics to recognise all pages with URL parameters as separate pages, and therefore track them individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually the default behaviour of Google Analytics, so in order to track these pages individually, you just need to use the default settings for your Google Analytics view.

Google Analytics will strip out the query parameters used for campaign tracking, but otherwise they make it through to reporting.

If you are not seeing query parameters coming in your page reports and you're certain that URLs with GA tracking on them are being accessed, check your filter settings and make sure you're not doing anything to strip them out.